# How boost write_some deals with the pointers?

Tags: c++, boost

[write_some](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/write_some/overload1.html) writes some data and returns. That is, it is nonblocking. Since the client has no way of knowing when the write ended, can I safely assume that `write_some` is responsible for deleting the pointer it received?

Comment: Side note: You are linking to the documentation of a very out-dated version of the boost library. There should be a notification box linking you to the most-recent version.

Comment: @walnut you're rigth. It expects a const_buffer, which has a pointer inside. Does this pointer get deleted by asio or by me?